# Trigger drag event of draggable handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Given this html...

```
<div class="item">
    <span class="handle">(handle)</span>
    <span> Drag using the "(handle)"</span>
</div><br/>
<div class="handle2">(handle2)</div>
```

...and this jQuery...

```
$('.item').draggable({helper:'clone', handle:'.handle'});

$('.handle2').mousedown(function(e){
    $('.handle').trigger(e);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wLsvsw5/

...Why is it that the drag event does not fire when dragging using (handle2)? ((handle) works as expected)

I can make it work when I remove the "handle" option in the draggable method...

```
$('.item').draggable({helper:'clone'});

$('.handle2').mousedown(function(e){
    $('.handle').trigger(e);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wLsvsw5/1/

What I am trying to do is trigger the drag event of the handle.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do similar thing and i found this workaround

```
$('.item').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});

$('.handle2').mousedown(function (event) {
    handle = $(".item").children(".handle");
    handle.trigger(event);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zksu352w/1/

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to make it work with the draggable "handle" option defined. In your answer you only have "helper" option, which is basically the same code at the last part of my question.